# Relocate all the evens

Tags: python, function

I'm supposed to remove any evens found in `info` and append them into the second argument, `house`. A reference to the list which received any evens must be returned. When no second argument is given, a list of all the relocated evens should be created and returned.

This is my code so far.

```
def relocate_even(info,house):
    house=[]
    new_list=[]
    for x in info:
        if x%2==0:
            info.remove(x)
            if len(house)>0:
                house.append(x)
                return house
            if len(house)<=0:
                new_list.append(x)
                return new_list
```

I'm having trouble with when the house function is empty. I have code written for that but it gives me an error.

Comment: `house` is not a function, it's a list. And it is always empty in your code, as you never put anything in it

Comment: `house` is a list. lists cannot have length less than zero. `len(house) < 0` will never evaluate to `True`. Also, why are you passing `house` into your function in the argument list and then setting `house` equal to an empty list? Any content that `house` had before entering your function will be lost after `house = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't modify iterables as you iterate over them.  That is to say, don't change `info` in a `for x in info:` block.  Instead create a new list and then set info equal to it. You can give an argument a default value, which allows for calls to not explicitly set that value.

```
def relocate_even(info, house=None):
    new_house = []
    new_info = []
    for x in info:
         if x%2:
             new_info.append(x)
         else:
             new_house.append(x)
    info[:] = new_info
    if house is None:
        return new_house
    else:
        house[:] = house + new_house
        return house
```

Comment: ok that makes so much sense! If I wanted to remove the even numbers in info, could I do that before appending into new_info?

Comment: `ix x%2` is basically the same thing as `if x%2 != 0`.  So all the odd numbers get appended to `new_info` and all the evens to `new_house`.  Then we replace the contents of `info` with the contents of `new_info`.  So there's no reason to do anything to `info` before building the two result lists